# tkinter смена окон по нажатию button

Tags: python, tkinter

Имею такоей код

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = 'cat.jpg'

zadanie = tk.Tk()
zadanie.title("Жизнь котика зависит только от Вас!")

image = Image.open(path)
width = 500
ratio = (width / float(image.size[0]))
height = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
image = image.resize((width, height))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


canvas = tk.Canvas(zadanie, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)

button = tk.Button(zadanie, text='Quit', command=zadanie.quit)
canvas.create_window((250, 250), anchor="nw", window=button)

canvas.create_text(250, 50, text="Засчитайте задание ради котика!", fill="Pink", font="Verdana 14")

zadanie.attributes('-toolwindow', True)
zadanie. resizable(False, False)
zadanie.mainloop()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию tk.button (изменю потом с выхода) менялась картинка фона и канвас? или как создать еще одно окно, по нажатию кнопки, чтобы на него переходило?

Comment: Что вы попробовали сделать и на чем сердце успокоилось?

Comment: Ну, создаете другую картинку, добавляете ее на канвас, старую убираете. Или создаете новый канвас с другой картинкой, старый убираете. Или создаете новое окно. Определитесь, что конкретно вам нужно, укажите какие проблемы в реализации задуманного у вас возникли.